# RGPD - GPDR : what did you do for the moment?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, gdpr

We try to find information about the famous law GPDR , but we can t see any example of a website which did something yet.
A user can ask to get all personnal information about him. How did you do that exactly ? 
Do you have any example ?

Thank you 
Thomas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after more expertise, i create a xml document with all informations of user , using this document : [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/gdpr/magento-1x.html)

I included logs , orders, quotes, customers informations , and newletters (all others things are not used by us)

I hope it'll help

The second step will to create a process to delete everything of a user (except orders, needed during 5 years in france... )

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

A lot of websites are actually taking a pretty subtle / less explicit  approach than you'd think. Check out Twitter, for example -- there's simply a bar on the bottom of the page with the text "Twitter has a new Terms of Service and Privacy Policy, effective May 25, 2018. Learn more", with "Learn More" linked to their Privacy Policy and "Got It" button to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

Check This Materials It Will Benefit you.

- For GDPR **Informaton** Please Check This [Here](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-gdpr-and-you-5-things-know-right-now).
- For Video**Video** For Explanation [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xy_afgALSI&feature=youtu.be).
- For Magento 2 **Demo** Module You can Download From [Here](https://github.com/AdFabConnect/magento2gdpr).